# Difference between a column of two constitutive rows in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to calculate difference between one column of two constitutive rows of a table.
The table structure is as follows (it's a demo):

```
Table:

 Id Name Age

 1  xman  30

 2  yman  40

 3  zman  55
```

So, In this table I need to calculate difference between age and if Age is greater than 10 than I need to fetch that person name.
Is it possible through SQL?
How can I do this please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL you can use [User Defined Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html) to get previous row values:

```
SELECT Name 
FROM
(  SELECT T.*,
       @prev as previousAge,
       @prev:=Age
   FROM T,(SELECT @prev:=NULL) as t1
   ORDER BY ID
) as T3
WHERE Age-previousAge>10
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e359d/10)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You must join the table to itself based either on the ID if the IDs are consecutive or on a calculated column like this:

```
select ...
from mytable a join mytable b where b.id = a.id - 1
where ...
```